# Bokeh chart in Django returning a blank page

Tags: python, django, bokeh

I'm trying to work through a [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/integrating-bokeh-visualisations-into-django-projects-a1c01a16b67a) to show a simple bokeh chart on a django page, but the web page is blank when it loads - there's no chart.

There was a similar Stack Overflow question where the wrong version of bokeh was referenced in the html file - I checked to make sure that's not the case here. I also tried to use the render function, as render_to_response is apparently being deprecated, but the same thing happened.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.0.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.0.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
        {{ script | safe }}
        <title>testing bokeh...</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        {{ div | safe }}
    </body>
</html>
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.embed import components
def bokehTutorial(request):
    x, y, = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    #Setup graph plot
    plot = figure(title = 'Line Chart', x_axis_label = 'X axis', y_axis_label = 'Y axis', plot_width = 400, plot_height = 400)
    #plot line
    plot.line(x, y, line_width = 2)
    #store components
    script, div = components(plot)
    #return to django homepage with components sent as arguments which will then be displayed
    return render_to_response('appName/bokehTutorial.html', {'script': script, 'div': div})
    #return render(request, 'appName/bokehTutorial.html', {'script': script, 'div': div})
```

I expect the web page to show a line chart. However, the web page appears blank when it loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to put the `div` first because the `script` is searching for it to put the code into it. Also simply use `INLINE.render()` or `CDN.render()` to link the resources automatically (unless you know what you are doing). So try the following:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        {{ resources | safe }}
        <title>testing bokeh...</title>
    </head>  
    <body>
        {{ div | safe }}
        {{ script | safe }}
    </body>
</html>
```

django_app.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.resources import INLINE

def bokehTutorial(request):
    x, y, = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    #Setup graph plot
    plot = figure(title = 'Line Chart', x_axis_label = 'X axis', y_axis_label = 'Y axis', plot_width = 400, plot_height = 400)
    #plot line
    plot.line(x, y, line_width = 2)
    #store components
    script, div = components(plot)
    #return to django homepage with components sent as arguments which will then be displayed
    return render_to_response('appName/bokehTutorial.html', {'resources' = INLINE.render(), 'script': script, 'div': div})
```

Answer (score 0):

Im getting a synthax error for the last line. Thoughts ?
return render('fish/ticket_class.html', {'resources' = INLINE.render(), 'script': script, 'div': div})

Comment: `'resources' = INLINE.render()` should be `'resources': INLINE.render()`